# How to get checkbox label to be on the left of checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code:

```
   <div class=checkbox>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="foo">My Label</label>
   </div>

   <div class=checkbox>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="bar">Another Longer</label>
   </div>

   <div class=checkbox>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="baz">Less than lng</label>
   </div>
```

this will render in bootstrap 3 with the label on the right hand side. which is fine normally, but I need it to be on the right hand side with the checkbox on the left.

So it looks like below, the labels should be right justified also.

```
      My Label []
Another longer []
 Less than lng []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can put your `checkbox` divs in a container, you don't have to worry about setting a width:

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.checkbox {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  text-align: right;
}

.checkbox input {
  float: right;
}
```

The border is needed for IE and Chrome.  (Note that I made it transparent.)  Stumbled across that by accident and will try to figure out why it's needed.

`white-space: nowrap` is needed for IE only.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaeg50hk/2/)

---

**Update**

We need to override some of Bootstrap's defaults.

`container` is a Bootstrap class, so I've changed to `cbcontainer`.

Bootstrap makes the inputs `position: absolute`, so I've changed to `position: relative !important`.

Also, a margin is now needed for the input.

Finally, the border is no longer needed for IE and Chrome, and `white-space` is no longer needed for IE.

Updated CSS:

```
.cbcontainer {
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox {
  text-align: right;
}

.checkbox input {
  float: right;
  position: relative !important;
  margin: 5px !important;
}
```

[**New Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/72y2r844/)

Comment: sorry but this doesn't work for bootstrap: see my fiddl http://jsfiddle.net/krystan/vaeg50hk/3/

Comment: Sorry I didn't test for that originally.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: what a great answer.. thanks so much I can't believe to be honest this isn't a more asked question.

Answer (score 2):

```css
label{float:left}
```

```html
 <div class=checkbox>
       <input type="checkbox" id="foo"><label>My Label</label>
   </div>

   <div class=checkbox>
       <input type="checkbox" id="bar"><label>Another Longer</label>
   </div>

   <div class=checkbox>
       <input type="checkbox" id="baz"><label>Less than lng</label>
   </div>
```

for perfect alignment, even if many designers won't like it, I would do this

```
<table><tr>
       <td><label>My Label</label></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" id="foo"></td>
</tr><tr>
       <td><label>Another Longer</label></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" id="bar"></td>
</tr><tr>
       <td><label>Less than lng</label></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" id="baz"></td>
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try set `float` to `left`, for `input` inside `.checkbox`.

For smooth alignement, You will set width of `.checkbox` and `label`.

To align text of label, to right You must set `text-align` to `right`.

Additional You must set `margin-left` for `input` for space between label text and checkbox `input`.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew18uuo7/1/)**

[image]

**CSS:**

```
.checkbox, .checkbox label {
    width: 200px;
}

.checkbox label {
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
}
.checkbox input {
    margin-left: 16px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: because the label wraps the input this floats the entire lot over to the right hand side of the current container and keeps the old alignment.